# cross-window javascript events

Tags: jquery, dhtml

I am launching a popup window with window.open(...) and I pass an elementId to the new popup window.

Then during startup of the popup window I find the element in the opener window that matches the elementId passed to the popup.  Then the popup subscribes to events on that element using jQuery.bind(...).  Then from inside the opener window I fire these events using jQuery.trigger(...), I also tried triggerHandlers.

The problem is that my popup's eventHandlers never get called.  I can subscribe to the events from within inside the opener window no problem.  However, when I try from the popup, it doesn't work.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?  Is this some kind of security description?

Thanks a lot for reading!

Comment: Use firefox firebug and check for errors. Then you will know weather it's security or just simple code error. Sample code would help.

Comment: Can you post some examples of the triggering you're attempting? I think you're probably trying to do it on elements matching the selector in the current window, rather than the opener, that's usually the case.

Comment: I've definitely got the correct element from the proper window.

Comment: Also, unfortunately I cannot use firefox in my lame environment, but there are no errors.

Comment: If you can't use Firefox, how are you going to make sure it *works* in Firefox?

Comment: I'm not going to make sure it works in firefox.  This is intranet.

Comment: Ah.  OK, "internet man" :-)  Here's another question: how exactly are you finding the opener page element from the popup page?  In other words, exactly what does the Javascript look like?  Do you just say (in the popup page) `$('#' + theId).click(...)` ? If so, are you even sure that jQuery is finding the element?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, when I find the "opener" page element and assign handlers this way:

```
// in the popup page
$(function() {
  var openerElement = window.opener.document.getElementById(theElementId);
  $(openerElement).click(function() {
    alert("Hello World!");
  });
});
```

Then, to my surprise, native "real" events work just fine. **However**, custom events fired from the opener page do **not** get picked up by the popup page.  That sort of makes sense, as each page has its own little jQuery universe.  I was apparently wrong however about the browser not propagating native events, so thanks for today's learning experience!!

*more info* — From the popup window (and similarly from any child `<iframe>` of the main document), you can also use

```
var thing_in_main_window = window.opener.$('#thingId');
```

to find stuff in the opener window. However, simply using the jQuery object *in the popup page* to find that element cannot work, because jQuery will not traverse the "window.opener" link and go hunting for the element there. When you call `$('#thingId')` on the popup page, jQuery is just going to called `document.getElementById('thingId')` using the `document` object for the **popup** page. If there's no element called "thingId" on that page, it won't be found.

*original answer:*

I don't think that what you're trying to do will work. The browser is not going to trigger any event handlers in a window different from the one containing the target element.

You can, however, catch the event in one window and then trigger a custom event in the other window. When you do that, you're probably going to want to trigger the event through the jQuery object on that page. In other words, you'd do this:

```
$('#thing').click(function() {
  otherWindow.jQuery.trigger("thing-clicked");
});
```

Comment: Well it's just my experience, and it's pretty easy to test with a really simple experiment page (or pages I guess).  I suppose I can't say I'm 100% positive that it's always true in every browser; I'll write a quick test and update my answer if I'm wrong of course!

Comment: thanks again.
var openingControl = window.opener.document.getElementById(openingControlId);  works but $("#" + openingControlId, window.opener.document); does not.

Comment: or actually both those lines find the element, but events don't work on the second one.

Comment: Are you *sure* that, from the popup page, that `$('#' + something)` really finds the element?  I don't see how that's possible, because on the popup page jQuery will just be looking in that DOM; it does not traverse `window.opener` and also look there. At least, I don't think it does; I can write another test.

Comment: I've created a new button hidden and I trigger my events on it, you helped a lot!

Comment: This is beautiful. I'm using this to connect my popup window back to my main window, because `window.open(...)` is sometimes asynchronous in modern browsers.  For example if the browser blocks the popup window, but then the user tells the browser to open it anyway, the popup window could succeed even though `window.open(...)` initially returned `null`.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Pointy for the answer. I experimented with this and want share my findings. You can actually define your event listeners in the popup window without referencing the opener:

**in the page opened as popup:**

```
$(document).on("foo", function() { 
  alert("foo"); 
});
```

**in the page which opens the popup:**

```
var popup = window.open("popup.html", "_blank", "width=500");
$("#trigger-button").on("click", function() {
  popup.$(popup.document).trigger("foo");
});
```

The secret is: even if you invoke jQuery from popup window object, you can't use selectors directly, because jQuery will try to find elements in the parent (opener) window.

Comment: I suppose you could work around that last issue by specifying the other window as the selector context. `popup.$('#thing', popup.document).trigger('foo');`