# Detecting when popup window is closed in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I open a new window like this:

```
var newWindow = window.open('myPage.aspx', null, 'height=650,width=900,status=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,location=no,top=0, left=0');
```

And I wait for it to close:

```
var windowTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
    if (win.closed !== false) {
        //If window is closed ...
        window.clearInterval(windowTimer);
    }
}, 100);
```

This does work in Chrome and IE9 and Edge **but not in Firefox, why**?

Firefox does get inside the function but it never gets on `win.closed if`, even if there is an `else` it neither goes into it... **is there any alternative to this?**

**Solution that worked for me:**

On the popup window:

```
    //Fires an event on the window that opened it
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        window.opener.myEvent();
    };
```

On the main window:

```
window.myEvent= function () {
//This fires only when the popup gets closed on beforeunload
}
```

**Note:** the event to fire in the main window must be declared as public so it can be accessible, like so `window.myEvent= function ()`

**Another reference:** [cross-window javascript events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188958/cross-window-javascript-events)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to execute a function `onBeforeUnload` in the newly opened window that will tell your old window that its been closed? (also, where is `win` defined?) - You can easily create a boolean in your parent window that you could access using `window.opener[key]` and write a value into it that your interval could pick up on, and that should work in FF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, I think the simplest way to do this is the following:

```js
function hasClosed(){
  document.getElementById('open').textContent = 'window has been closed';
}
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(){
  if(window.opener) window.opener.hasClosed();
});
document.getElementById('open').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  window.open('test.html');
});
```

```html
<a href="#" id="open">open window</a>
```

Please keep in mind that SO snippets are not allowed to open windows, so the code is not functional inside the snippet. Simply copy the code and save it as a file called `test.html`.

You do not need to keep checking, the child will simply call the function on the parent. This has the advantage that you are not using resources to keep checking for it. Also, be aware that when navigating in this window, `onbeforeunload` gets called if a new page is loaded, calling the parent function, but maybe you could just do the check you were already doing in the `hasClosed` function.

You might want to give an `uuid` to your window and pass it into it so it can inform you of it's identity on closing, but that's all refinement.

Comment: @Alpha2k Yeah to be honest, I used this once about a year ago and was surprised to find how simple this is :) Good luck!